# Error loading imageurl from json in kotlin

Tags: arrays, json, image, kotlin, integer

I'm currently trying to build an Android app. I'm following this tutorial at the moment:
https://www.javatpoint.com/kotlin-android-custom-listview

But unlike the example in the tutorial, I get my image url's from a json file.
It does read the right image url from my JSON file. But I get this error:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "R.drawable.firstimage"
```

This image does exist in my android project. And it works when I load it hardcoded in an imageview.
This are the parts of my code that I think should contain the problem:

main kotlin file:

```
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_producten, container, false)
    val json_text = v.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.json_listp)
    var json : String? = null
    var arr = arrayListOf<String>()
    var fam = arrayListOf<String>()
    var img = arrayListOf<Int>()


    try {
        val pro: InputStream = context?.assets!!.open("products.json")
        json = pro.bufferedReader().use { it.readText()}

        var jsonarr = JSONArray(json)

        for (i in 0..jsonarr.length()-1)
        {
            var jsonobject = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i)
            arr.add(jsonobject.getString("name"))
            fam.add("type")
            img.add(jsonobject.getString("image").toInt())
        }
        val product_adapter = MyProductAdapter(requireActivity(), arr, fam, img)
        json_text.adapter = product_adapter
    }
    catch (e : IOException) {

    }
    return v
```

This is the product_adapter class:

```
class MyProductAdapter(
private val context: Activity,
private val title: ArrayList<String>,
private val description: ArrayList<String>,
private val imgid: ArrayList<Int>)
: ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.row_producten, title) {

override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val inflater = context.layoutInflater
    val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_producten, null, true)

    val titleText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mainrowtitle) as TextView
    val imageView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.productview) as ImageView
    val subtitleText = rowView.findViewById(R.id.rowdescrition) as TextView

    titleText.text = title[position]
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position])
    subtitleText.text = description[position]

    return rowView
}
}
```

I really hope someone can spot the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `R.drawable.firstimage` (a string) in your JSON response, then try to `toInt()` it, hence the `NumberFormatException`.

You instead need to take your drawable name (e.g. `firstimage`), and fetch the int ID from the resources when building `img`, using something like:

```
val resourceId = context.resources.getIdentifier("firstimage", "drawable", context.packageName)
```

Make sure you are passing in just the drawable name, and not `R.drawable.` before it.

Comment: This totally fixed my problem. Thank you very much!